# remove null from an array

Tags: php, laravel

i want to import csv to database , how ever i got this error : 
code : 
ErrorException array_combine(): Both parameters should have an equal number of elements
i know that the error shows that the two arrays arent in the same length how ever i couldnt find a solution to remove the null value from an array

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Accounts;
class AccountController extends Controller
{
    public function show(){
        return view ('upload');
    }
    public function store(Request $request){


        $file = $request->file('upload-file');
        $csvData = file_get_contents($file);

        $rows = array_map("str_getcsv", explode("\n", $csvData));

        dd($rows);
        $header = array_shift($rows);

        foreach ($rows as $row) {


            $row = array_combine($header, $row);



            set_time_limit(0);
            Accounts::create([
                'AccountClass' => $row['Classe'],
                'AccountNumber' => $row['Compte'],
                'AccountDesc' => $row['Desc'],
                'active' => 1,
            ]);
        }

        return view ('home');

    }

}
```

Result:
header :

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => "Classe"
  1 => "Compte"
  2 => "Desc"
]
```

rows :

```
   array:4 [▼
      0 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "1"
        2 => "COMPTES DE FINANCEMENT PERMANENT"
      ]
      1 => array:3 [▼
        0 => "1"
        1 => "11"
        2 => "CAPITAUX PROPRES"
      ]
      2 => array:1 [▼
        0 => null
      ]
    ]
```

But I want

```
   array:4 [▼

          0 => array:3 [▼
            0 => "1"
            1 => "1"
            2 => "COMPTES DE FINANCEMENT PERMANENT"
          ]
          1 => array:3 [▼
            0 => "1"
            1 => "11"
            2 => "CAPITAUX PROPRES"
          ]
        ]
```

Any advice greatly appreciated.

Comment: Take a look at [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) function.

Comment: Check the php function array_filter(), without a callback it cleans null values. Perhaps you need to create a callback because the null is inside another array.

Comment: `$csvData = trim($csvData);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
$res = [];
foreach($x as $key => $value)
{
if($value[0] == null)
unset($x[$key]);
else
$res[$key] = $value;
}
print_r($res);
```

Output will be

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 1
        [2] => COMPTES DE FINANCEMENT PERMANENT
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [0] => 1
        [1] => 11
        [2] => CAPITAUX PROPRES
    )

)
```

Answer (score 1):

Since laravel is tagged on this question, might I suggest using [collection](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/eloquent-collections).

```
$array = [1, 2, 3, null, 4];
$array = collect($array)->filter()->values()->toArray();
```

Here, **filter()** will remove *null* values and **value()** will *re-index* your array.

Hope it helps. Cheers.